# innerHTML.indexOf when reloading div not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following script. It works fine if I reload the page but I would prefer to make it work with just reloading the div but it seems that innerHTML.indexOf doesn't pick up on changes in a div without reloading the whole page which looks a bit ugly. How can I check for the string in the logs div without using location.reload()?

```
<div id="logs"><?php echo nl2br( file_get_contents('/path/myfile') ); ?></div>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 2000);
function myTimer() {
 $("#logs").load(window.location.href + " #logs" );
 location.reload();
}

if (document.getElementById("logs").innerHTML.indexOf("thisistheend") != -1) {
  clearInterval(myVar);
}
</script>
```

edit: I also tried putting the conditional inside the myTimer function but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare if statement inside of `myTimer`. Otherwise, the if statement will only be executed once on the first render.

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 2000);
function myTimer() {
  $("#logs").load(window.location.href + " #logs" );
  if (document.getElementById("logs").innerHTML.indexOf("thisistheend") != -1) {
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }
}
```